# Reassign string character

Tags: vim

I have the following VimScript commands:

```
let str="abc"
echo str        # => abc
echo str[1]     # => b
let str[1]="@"  # => E689: Can only index a List, Dictionary or Blob
```

It seems that VimScript has no support for string indexing in assignments. So my question is how can I resign the second character of `str` so that it becomes `a@c`?

My current solution is:

```
let str=substitute(str,"\\%2c.","@","")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that VimScript has no support for string indexing in assignments.

You mean no index is allowed on the left-hand side. But it's still possible to use it on the rhs. Perhaps, this cannot be called brief, but nonetheless it's quite readable:

```
let str = str[0] . '@' . str[2:]
```

Comment: Nice, I think this is more readable than my original  solution.